Do elements positioned with percentage does not have transition effect?
I have literally taken days to understand percentPosition given in the article Masonry. I am still not sure if I understood it  correctly or not. It is mentioned in article that

Sets item positions in percent values, rather than pixel values.
percentPosition: true works well with percent-width items, as items
will not transition their position on resize.

What I clearly understood is that items positioned with percent values works well when items width are set through percent. Now the the following part where I was struggling to understand which is

as items will not transition their position on resize

After reading and experimenting a lot, I have understood that transition does not happen when elements are positioned with percentage while with elements position with pixel values transition do happen (not aware of the reason)
I have just written a small code to demonstrate my understanding. Please let me know If my understanding aligned with the article and it is correct or not.
Basically there are three divs: bigdiv(parent div), rel-div(positioned with percent values) and fix-div(positioned with pixel). When parent div's width is 600px or greater,I relocated fix-div  to new position and we can see transition effect on this pixel positioned element. While  there is no transition effect no matter what  width I set for parent width through input.


o      = document.querySelector(".bigdiv")
fixDiv = document.querySelector(".fix-div")
inp    = document.querySelector("#inp")
inp.addEventListener('change', e => {
  o.style.width = e.target.value + "px"
})
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => {
  console.log('Width:', o.offsetWidth, 'Height:', o.offsetHeight);
  if (o.offsetWidth >= 600) {
    fixDiv.style.left = "120px"
  } else {
    fixDiv.style.left = "20px"
  }
});
resizeObserver.observe(o)
.bigdiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: horizontal;
  position: relative;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.rel-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  transition: left ease 1s;
}

.fix-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  transition: left ease 1s;
}
<div class="bigdiv">
  <div class="fix-div"></div>
  <div class="rel-div"></div>
</div>
<br>
<lable>Width:</lable>
<input type="number" name="" id="inp">



I was going through Masonry JS article. I percentPosition

You're mixing everything up: the recommendations on using percentages in the Masonry library only concern the Masonry library. Trying to draw general conclusions from them is the best way to mislead your mind.
I even suspect that you used chatGPT to compose this question.

But if you change the percentage positioning the same way you are changing the pixel positioning you will see that the transition is indeed animated for the percentage example. This is a poor code sample reinforcing an incorrect assumption.

@MisterJojo, Thanks for your response. Yes I had used chat gpt to get the answer of question,but question and code is mine. Could you please let me know what exactly the statement,from Masonry Library trying to convey ?

@pilchard, may you suggest the changes in code so that I can see transition on percent positioned item.

Masonry Library is just an interface layer. Its name is directly related to the work of a mason who has to build a wall with stones of random sizes.

So, it's not true that items positioned with percentvalues do not have transition? Please bear with me If anyway I am bothering you.

Just because something is verifiable in one context doesn't mean it can be in another. It seems that you are missing some principles in your system of thought...

To see transition on the percentage divs just apply the same code that you are using on your pixel positioned divs on the percentage positioned divs — here is a jsfiddle

@MisterJojo,I am just trying to understand how Masonry are working under the hood. May be the way I was trying to understand is not correct, and I think that's where the SO helps. Anyways, Any suggestion to improve my system of thought ?
